# Blocking main thread when first navigate to page

Tags: c#, performance, user-interface, uwp, entity-framework-core

## Problem

When the app starts, an empty `Home` page opens. I go to the `Vendors` tab and it freezes for a few seconds (I can see that the UI is frozen). After that, the `Vendors` page is displayed. The elements contain data from the database.

You might think that the lock was caused by loading data from the database. But it occurs in the `async/await` methods.

If after one loaded of `Vendors` to return to `Home` and back to `Vendors` - there is no freeze. The page opens almost instantly. In this case, the data loading mechanism also occurs (by the `Loaded event`)

It turns out that the freeze is only from a clean start when first visit the `Vendros` page. What could be the problem?

## GIF

[image]

## Code

**View**

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ic:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <ic:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.PageLoadedCommand}" />
    </ic:EventTriggerBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

**VendorsViewModel**

```
public ICommand PageLoadedCommand {get;}
private async void OnPageLoaded(RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    await VendorsService.InitializeAsync();

    BankItems = VendorsService.BankItems;
    AuthorityItems = VendorsService.AuthorityItems;
    VendorItems = VendorsService.VendorItems;
}

public ObservableCollection<VendorModel> VendorItems {get; set;}
public ObservableCollection<TwoLinesModel> BankItems {get; set;}
public ObservableCollection<TwoLinesModel> AuthorityItems{get; set;}
```

**VendorService**

```
private TwoLinesService<BankEntity> BankService { get; } = new TwoLinesService<BankEntity>();
private TwoLinesService<AuthorityEntity> AuthorityService { get; } = new TwoLinesService<AuthorityEntity>();

public ObservableCollection<VendorModel> VendorItems { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<TwoLinesModel> BankItems { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<TwoLinesModel> AuthorityItems { get; private set; }

public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    await BankService.InitializeAsync();
    await AuthorityService.InitializeAsync();

    VendorItems = new ObservableCollection<VendorModel>
    {
        new VendorModel { Name = "Name 1", Surname = "Surname 1", Patronymic = "MiddleName 1", IssueDate = new DateTime(2020, 2, 9) },
        new VendorModel { Name = "Name 2", Surname = "Surname 2", Patronymic = "MiddleName 2", IssueDate = new DateTime(2019, 3, 7) }
    };
    BankItems = BankService.Items;
    AuthorityItems = AuthorityService.Items;

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**TwoLinesService**

```
public class TwoLinesService<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : TwoLinesEntity, new()
{
    private IDataServiceFactory<TEntity> DataServiceFactory { get; } = new DataServiceFactory<TEntity>();
    public ObservableCollection<TwoLinesModel> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TwoLinesModel>();

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        using var dataService = DataServiceFactory.Create();

        foreach (var entity in await dataService.SelectAll())
        {
            Items.Add(CreateModel(entity));
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public TwoLinesModel CreateModel(TEntity source)
    {
        return new TwoLinesModel
        {
            ID = source.ID,
            Title = source.Title,
            Text = source.Text,
            CreatedOn = source.CreatedOn,
            LastModifiedOn = source.LastModifiedOn
        };
    }
}
```

**DataServiceFactory**

```
public class DataServiceFactory<T> : IDataServiceFactory<T> where T : DomainEntity
{
    public IDataService<T> Create()
    {
        return Configuraiton.Current.DataProvider switch
        {
            DataProviderType.SQLite => new SQLiteService<T>(Configuraiton.Current.SQLiteConnectionString),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
        };
    }
}
```

**SelectAll()**

```
public partial class GenericDataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T : DomainEntity
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    public GenericDataService(DbContext dbContext) => _dbContext = dbContext;

    public async Task<IList<T>> SelectAll()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is inside `DataServiceFactory.Create()` and `dataService.SelectAll()`. And is there any reason why you call it twice, or is that just a typo?

Comment: @Euphoric yes, is typo. I added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

I managed to find a bottleneck. The program is an early stage of development. During startup, the program does not call methods associated with the database. I detected with help `Debug Output` that the first time calls `DataServiceFactory.Create()` is loaded new components. Immediately after this, the user interface freeze ends.

```
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Linq.Expressions.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly". 
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Data.Common.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Transactions.Local.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.Timer.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Threading.Thread.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Buffers.dll".
"ProgramName.exe" (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain). Loaded "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27909.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Memory.dll".
```

## Solution

The main solution is to load data at startup. At this stage, there is nothing to load.

I find two temporary solutions.

- Call the factory creation in the `App.xaml.cs`. This loads most of the components.

```
var dataServiceFactory = new DataServiceFactory<VendorEntity>();
var dataService = dataServiceFactory.Create();
```

- Or initiate a start in the event handler `OnPageLoaded()` using `Task.Run()`

```
private async void OnPageLoaded(RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    await Task.Run(() => VendorsService.InitializeAsync());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That might be a common pitfall in asynchronous programming on UWP. To use async/await/Task is not equivalent to run the code in background thread. If you'd like to do some time-consuming task in the background thread, you need to wrap it in Task.Run(). Or otherwise UI-thread will be blocked.

Try using Task.Run in the SelectAll() in anyway.

```
public Task<IList<T>> SelectAll()
{
    return Task.Run(async ()=> { return await _dbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync(); });
}
```